# how can get radio value from page A to page B and set checked?

Tags: javascript, php

how can get radio value from page A?

in the page A, I have this code in page A

```
{* "ship","$60","$60","$70","$70","$65","$65" *}
{$pay=array("Payment","CreditCard","Ship","ATM","Store","LINE Pay","Google Pay")}
<li>
    <ul class="flex pay radiobox">
        {foreach $pay as $key => $value}
            <li>{if $key>0}<input type="radio" name="pay" value="{$key}">{/if}{$value}</li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
</li>
{$dleveily=array("Delivery","$60","$60","$70","$70","$65","$65")}
<li>
    <ul class="flex dleveily radiobox">
        {foreach $dleveily as $key => $value}
            <li>{if $key>0}<input type="radio" name="dleveily" value="{$key}">
                <img src="/themes/LifeHouse/img/lifegoproduct/dleveily_{$key}-07.svg">{/if}{$value}
            </li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
</li>
```

I can get value from page A in page B, but how can set ckecked?

this is page b code

```
<input class="" type="radio" id="payway" name="payway" value="2">Credit Card</span>
<input class="" type="radio" id="payway" name="payway" value="5">Ship</span>
<input class="" type="radio" id="payway" name="payway" value="2">ATM</span>
<input class="" type="radio" id="payway" name="payway" value="5">Store</span>
```

if when I use this code

```
$paymethod = $_POST['pay'];
```

how can set correct checked in radio button?

Comment: What happen if value coming as 2, according to your current HTML of page B, 2 radio buttons having same value and then they both have to be checked, which is not possible in case of radio button

Comment: if page a send values as 2 to pagg b, I want to use this value to check radio button.

Comment: As i said you have 2 radio button with same value 2. so both needs to be checked according to you? which is not possible in case of radio button

Comment: Explain where those values of the radio buttons in page B come from? On page A, you used the array key for the radio button value, so there _can not_ have been any duplicate values within one radio button group. But now on page B, suddenly there are?

Comment: @CBroe So don't need to set the value on page B, just grab the one sent from page A?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I mean, there are currently five radio buttons on page A. When the user clicks on one of them, it will be sent directly to page B and then correspond to the same radio button. If the user click the credit card item. its values is 2 then when user click the next, I hope I can get values 2 to set values 2 is checked in page B

Comment: @StanleyTas you said __I hope I can get values 2 to set values 2 is checked in page B __ -> but the thing is on page B you have 2 radio button with value 2 , so my question is how to determine which radio button has to be checked?